# Redmine gui rendering issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, reverse-proxy, redmine

we are using this redmine instance for some time now in the intranet, but from one day to another nearly all forms in redmine look like this. It is the same in firefox, chrome and safari. I also opened a different redmine instance from another server in the same chrome browser, which looks fine.

[image]

Not affected is the login form, the search boxes and the filter boxes. Also the wiki works fine.

I cannot remember having changed a setting that could have done this. I also tried changing the skin from standard to classic or alternate, which did not help.

Version info says `Redmine 1.0.2.stable (PostgreSQL)` Server is ubuntu 10.04 64, Client is win3k-32.

The last thing I did was adding a new project.

**Update:**

The site is reverse proxied over a https apache2 in our intranet. I just found out that served directly from the original machine (with mongrel on http port 9001) everything is fine, so I guess apache filters something. Any ideas?

Maybe a resource like a css link is not properly rewritten?

This is the vhost file from the proxy:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.186:80>

    ServerName redmine.cgnch.de

    ErrorLog /var/www/redmine_http_error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/redmine_http_access_log combined

    #Re-write any HTTP request to HTTPS
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R=permanent]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.1.1.186:443>

    ServerName redmine.example.com

    ErrorLog /var/www/redmine_ssl_error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/redmine_ssl_access_log combined

    #Configure Reverse Proxy
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    #Rewrite Engine for URLs in HTML, JS and css:
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    # ProxyHTMLEnable On
    # On: rewrite also css and javascript - Off: only in HTML
    ProxyHTMLExtended Off

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://10.1.1.185:9001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.1.185:9001/


        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://10.1.1.185:9001 https://redmine.example.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

</Virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the following lines form the vhost file:

```
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLExtended Off
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://10.1.1.185:9001 https://redmine.example.com
```

It is not necessary to remap the hostnames, because redmine only uses relative addressing.

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser's error console. If it's something like an inaccessible stylesheet, an appropriate error message will be shown.

Comment: You mean the rails / mongrel logs? Where can I find them?

Comment: I actually meant the browser logs - what web browser are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you've sorted it.